# Obtaining Standard Errors in Optim() in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, standard-error, hessian

I'm using a maximum likelihood estimation and I'm using the `optim()` function in `R` in a similar way as follows:

`optim(c(phi,phi2, lambda), objf, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(-1.5, -1.5, 0), upper = c(1.5, 1.5, 1), model = model_gaussian)`

where `objf` is the function to estimate parameters given as:

```
objf <- function(pars, model, estimate = TRUE) {

model$T[is.na(model$T)] <- pars[c(1,2,3)] 

 if (estimate) {
-logLik(model)
} else {
model
}
}
```

(The `model$T` given above is for the `KFAS` package)

Now, I would like to obtain the standard errors (in order to calculate t-stats) for the parameters I am estimating. However, apparently since this optimisation is a constrained maximum likelihood estimation (due to the "L-BFGS-B") I cannot use the Hessian matrix to obtain standard errors since it would not be mathematically correct, so this means I can't just add `hessian=TRUE` to the `optim` line.

For example, if I were using the `BFGS`(which is not restricted/constrained) rather than the `L-BFGS-B` method, to find standard errors is pretty simple:

```
opt <- optim(c(phi,phi2, lambda), objf, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(-1.5, -1.5, 0), upper = c(1.5, 1.5, 1), model = model_gaussian, hessian = TRUE)
standarderrors <- sqrt(abs(diag(solve(-opt$hessian))))
```

For this reason I thought I'd ask: what's the best way to obtain standard errors for my problem? What is the appropriate method to going about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless your boundaries excluded the ML values of the parameters, I think you can still use the Hessian to obtain standard errors. Alternative methods could be bootstrap or jackknife.

Comment: @matteo I see, I thought for constrained MLE the Hessian matrix had issues so I was a bit concerned, especially since (at times) the standard errors obtained were very large. I'll look into it a bit more, thanks!